# what is the differences between LDA and MLR?

Tags: regression, classification, mathematical-statistics

I know that Linear Discrimination Analysis (LDA) is used for classification and Multiple Linear Regression (MLR) is for regression.
Lets say I have a matrix X (independent variables) and Y(dependent variables) 
if the Y is continues and I make a regression , it becomes MLR
if the Y is categories (like 1111122222) and I do MLR to make a relation , it becomes LDA?

can one explain it in simple words and illustrations ?

Comment: What are MLR and LDA?

Comment: @user777 I edited the question , have a look at above

Comment: Did you attempt to search this site? This topic was addressed several times here.

Comment: @ttnphns the first thing I always do is to search! , I did search but I could not find a straight answer to this question

Comment: @D L Dahly that is not the answer of my specific question. There are over million pages in the internet explaining the concept and theory behind each of these techniques. I simply asked how they are different if one performs MLR between categorised y values and X, would it counts as LDA? or not and what is the differences in simple words not blah blah